# Как в самом SQL задать значение по которому будет идти сравнение? (диалоговое окно)

Tags: sql

Мой код:

```
select 
    *
from 
    ORBFCUBS.FBTB_TILL_TOTALS u
where 
    u.TILL_ID = (
        select 
            d.Till_ID 
        from 
            ORBFCUBS.SMTB_USER_TILLS d 
        where 
            d.USER_ID = **Заданная переменная** 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы ранее объявляли переменную через declare - используйте оператор "@" для получения доступа к значению объявленной переменной по её имени.
Или можете просто прямо в запрос вписать значение в соответствующем формате (например, строки должны быть в кавычках).

Comment: Под заданной переменной я имел в виду переменную, которую можно ввести вручную. То есть, при запуске запроса выводилась диалоговое окно в которую я бы вводил Нужное значение по кторому шел бы поиск. Есть ли вообще в Sql Developer такая фишка?

Comment: Если есть, то можно пример, пожалуйста

Comment: @Фуркат, о такой фиче мне совершенно ничего неизвестно. Боюсь, на голом SQL такой функционал не реализовать.
Придется писать либо web-интерфейс, либо еще что-то, что будет реализовывать диалоговое окно и билд запроса с введенным параметром.

Comment: Не, такая фишка есть разве что в MS Access - и то потому, что он и СУБД, и клиент в одном флаконе, поскольку именно клиент, а не СУБД, выполняет запрос неизвестного ему значения параметра.